# Laravel +nginx: 403 Forbidden + 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, nginx

My nginx/conf.d/default.conf is :

```
location /manager/ {
            error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log ;
            alias /opt/www/manager;
            try_files $uri  $uri/ @laravel =404;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

            }

} location @laravel {
    rewrite /manager/(.*)$ /manager/index.php?/$1 last; }
```

But when I go to `localhost/manager` nginx say `403 Forbidden`.

**UPDATE**

I checked and the error was the last / in the location.
Now I have another problem with routes.
The api.php is as follows:

```
<?php
use App\Mail\Ripesature;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Router;

/** @var Router $api */
$api = app(Router::class); 
$api->version('v1', function (Router $api) {

  $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function (Router $api) {

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function (Router $api) {  
      $api->post('signup', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\SignUpController@signUp');
      $api->post('login', 'App\\Api\\V1\\Controllers\\LoginController@login'); 
    }
 }
}
```

But when the browser try to access `localhost/manager/api/v1/auth/login` nginx replies with `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Try `try_files $uri  $uri/ @laravel;` - the named location must be the last parameter of a `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: It does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of @Richard Smith the solution, according to the manual not very clear, is to put the named location as the last parameter.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel ;
```